# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2 + a^2} dk$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2 + a^2} dk$$

This equals to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2 + a^2} dk$ and I solved it, but the answer is not of exponential form. How do I evaluate this in exponential form?

Comment: "using taylor expansion" - nope; you'll be getting not a few divergent integrals that way.

Comment: @Aryabhata: no it isn't.  It's standard for an inverse Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

You might recognize this as a known Fourier transform:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \frac{e^{i k x}}{k^2+a^2} = \frac{\pi}{a} e^{-a |x|}$$

This may be derived via the Residue theorem by considering a similar integral in the complex plane.

Comment: Excuse-me @Ron Gordon, but could you elaborate a little on which integral of the complex plane should be integrated ? Exactly the same, but with $k$ a variable of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Rhaena: yes, and the contour can be a semicircle in the upper half plane.

Comment: Mmh so $C_R := \{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| = R, \Im(z) > 0\}$ can be usefull here ?